# Update number on AJAX, laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Basically what is happening is when I press the button then I get a +1 point on post. Everything is working excellent but I don't know how to update the number itself without page refresh. The info is already send to database I just don't know how to change number without page refresh.. This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.get(url, formData, function(response){

        });
    });
});
```

And my html:

```
<p>Not recommended: <strong><span id="votes" class="label label-success">{{$s->points}}</span></strong></p>
```

Comment: This has no connection to Laravel whatsoever. A less sophisticated way is to use jQuery to update the value, eg: $('span#votes').text(parseInt($('span#votes').text()) + 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the client side

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.get(url, formData, function(response){
            // This function runs when you successfully return
            $('#votes').html( response.newNumber );
        });
    });
});
```

And on the Laravel side

```
public function getVote(Request $request) {
    // Process form
    $points = 5;
    return response()->json(['newNumber' => $points]);
}
```

[More on $.get jQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Also, I don't know the nature of your app, but it's recommended that if you're making changes to data on the server side (i.e. upvoting a post) you use a [POST](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) request.

Answer (score 0):

Just query your span by it's id and replace it's text with the points (I'm assuming points is a property in the response, but this might be different)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.get(url, formData, function(response){
             $('#votes').text(response.points);
        });
    });
});
```